# How do I append a JSON object to a GET url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Making a GET request is easy, you just specify an URL in the href attribute of an anchor tag.

But, how do you add a JSON object to that URL?

I'm guessing this has to be done through jQuery... but I can't user AJAX, or the response isn't rendered by the browser.

so far, I've tried this: `$j("#gen").attr("href", $j("#gen").attr("href") + "?" + JSON.stringify({object: data}));` but it doesn't append the data. This is triggered onClick

Comment: What do you mean you can't use AJAX or the response isn't rendered? Are you just trying to generate a link?

Comment: yes, i'm just wanting to make an HTTP GET request so the server can redirect my browser, based on the data in teh params.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is no need for jQuery, you just have to encode the JSON properly: `<a href="foo?bar={&quot;some&quot;:&quot;value&quot;}">link</a>`. But I don't think you provide enough information (context) for your problem.

Comment: so far, I've tried this:   $j("#gen").attr("href", $j("#gen").attr("href") + "?" + JSON.stringify({object: data}));
 but it doesn't append the data. This is triggered onClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
jQuery("#gen").attr("href", jQuery("#gen").attr("href") + "?" + jQuery.param({object: data}));
```

Answer (score 3):

Any values in a GET request are expected to be URL encoded into the request string.

There is a [`jQuery.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) function that will do this for you, but all it does is serialize a set of name/value pairs as query string parameters.

I'm not really sure what you mean by not being able to use AJAX. Using jQuery you would do something like this:

```
$.get("foo/bar", { foo: "foo", bar: "bar" },
   function(data){
     $("#myTarget").append(data);
   });
```

Assuming of course the return value was HTML.

Ok, I think I understand a little better. If you just want to turn some object into a Query String, then you can roll your own function pretty easy:

```
function toQueryString(obj){
    var formattedVals = [];

    for(var prop in obj){
        formattedVals.push(prop + "=" + obj[prop]);
    }

    return formattedVals.join("&");
}
```

You can see how it would work by calling it this way:

```
var data = { foo: "foo", bar: "bar" };

alert(toQueryString(data));
```

Anyway, this should get you 90% of the way there.

Comment: +1 for the jQuery syntax to map the JSON to the querystring params.

Comment: @DerNalia - of course not... how exactly would you represent a nested structure with a simple name value pairing? Most implementations expect a simple object or dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

A GET request has querystring params.  If it's a GET request you really want, then you can map properties on the object to key value pairs on the request.

For example:

```
JSON object:  { prop1: val1, prop2: val2 } 
url get querystring:  ?prop1=val1&prop2=val2
```

But, if you want to send an object to the server, perhaps you really want a POST?  In that case, the JSON object would be in the body of the POST.